# Whats the value for EDI and Jokers romance?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I want them to love each other, but I fudged up and didn't get them to hook up on their own. How can I edit my save so they get together?

Comment: The usual editors have user-friendly checkboxes to select romances without need to know a value or whatever

Answer (score 1):

If you are just asking about Save File Editor then you can just use the checkboxes for romance. 
However if you have played ME2 then you have multiple occasions where you can basically you can convince Joker to work in co-operation with EDI. On ME3 whenever you land Citadel then talk to EDI and Joker and many times they will ask about their romance, you can give them good inputs to nourish the romantic relation between them. That way they slowly and steadily develop affection for each other.
Also in ME3 Ending, if you have enough points then you get a third option and if you select that then you get to see them being together in the end. I am not going to spoil that decision for you or the circumstances so not telling it briefly. :)